# What does the symbol "`\`" mean in the context of set operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning group by using this [post](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/vDv_IBtCEeiWORIdrorXgg_bc6c0f301b4211e8a1721fb14d2c5cb9_vector_spaces.pdf?Expires=1563062400&Signature=Qh47h07tw~ahkiTTcP8K1c8uKuVwFSahDPMftVpnXgM9HdlSKn5MO4jMycN2xivzsMjwP3J-iFx1OkpjGcf7CgiItjR5PVrU32oAnKguQJYSRy4UnNpPznUL5d3T~9qT~vNCVaYjxU0vBET6Bnaz90wog8D5Ss5O~TPDz3hNi1w_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

[image]

let's call this figure_1.

everything is OK until the `set of B` shows up.

what I already known is

The union is notated A ⋃ B

The intersection is notated A ⋂ B.

what I want to know is

what does the symbol "`\`" mean at the last paragraph in the figure_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the notation for the difference: $A \setminus B=\{x: x\in A, x \notin B\}$

Answer (score 3):

The operator $\setminus$ is the set difference defined by
$$A\setminus B=\{a\in A:a\not\in B\}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is "\setminus" ($\setminus$) and means [Set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).